# Why TJson.ObjectToJsonObject/ObjectToJsonString represents record fields as a JSON array?

Tags: json, delphi, records, superobject, delphi-xe7

There is an inconsistency of how SuperObject and TJson.ObjectToJsonObject represent certain parts of a class (i.e. Record fields). Let's have the following code snippet:

```
Uses rest.json, superobject;

  type

      TSimplePersonRec = record
        FirstName: string;
        LastName: string;
        Age: byte;
      end;

      TSimplePerson = class
        protected
          FPersonRec: TSimplePersonRec;
        public
          property personRecord: TSimplePersonRec read FPersonRec write FPersonRec;
      end;

    // ...

        { Public declarations }
        function toJson_SO(simplePerson: TSimplePerson): string;
        function toJson_Delphi(simplePerson: TSimplePerson): string;

    // ...

    function TForm1.toJson_Delphi(simplePerson: TSimplePerson): string;
    begin
      result := tjson.Format(TJson.ObjectToJsonObject(simplePerson));
    end;

    function TForm1.toJson_SO(simplePerson: TSimplePerson): string;
    var
      so: ISuperObject;
      ctx: TSuperRttiContext;
    begin
      ctx := TSuperRttiContext.Create;
      try
        so := ctx.AsJson<TSimplePerson>( simplePerson );
      finally
        ctx.Free;
      end;
      result := so.AsJSon(true, true);
    end;

    // ...

    procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      spr: TSimplePersonRec;
      sp: TSimplePerson;
    begin

      spr.FirstName := 'John';
      spr.LastName := 'Doe';
      spr.Age := 39;

      sp := TSimplePerson.Create;
      sp.personRecord := spr;

      memo1.Lines.Add(#13'--- SuperObject ---'#13);
      memo1.Lines.Add(toJson_SO(sp));
      memo1.Lines.Add(#13'---   Delphi    ---'#13);
      memo1.Lines.Add(toJson_Delphi(sp));
    end;
```

The OUTPUT is:

```
--- SuperObject ---
{
 "FPersonRec": {
  "LastName": "Doe",
  "Age": 39,
  "FirstName": "John"
 }
}
---   Delphi    ---
{
  "personRec":
  [
    "John",
    "Doe",
    39
  ]
}
```

What's the reason for Delphi to represent records as JSON array? Is there a public standard or suggestion leading to this?

**Note:**
*For me it's more natural to represent records with {key: value} notation instead of array. Not knowing the key name to witch the value belongs may have strange results during deserialization. For Example during deserialization I could pass a new class with the same layout, containing a record with different memory layout. In this case the values will be randomly assigned or an AV could occur?*

**UPDATE:**
I'm using Delphi XE7.
Also I found this of json.org:

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> - A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>     list, or associative array.
> - An ordered list of values. In most
>     languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

So probably the question is more about is this a bug in TJson unit?

Comment: What problem is `TJson` attempting to solve? Is it attempting to be a comprehensive JSON library? Or is it just trying to do what is needed for whatever uses it? Surely you'd just do what everyone else does and use superobject always.

Comment: json.org says: JSON is built on two structures: 1) A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array. 2) An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence. ## So the question is about is this a bug in TJSON unit?

Comment: Which version of Delphi, btw.?

Comment: My version is Delphi XE7

Comment: Interesting test. I would expect it to behave like SuperObject too. But it's hard to answer the actual question. If the output is not incorrect per se, it could be a feature. And if it's a bug because it's undocumented behaviour, then every feature that was added since Delphi 7 is basically a bug. ;-)

Comment: It would be informative to show how a class of the same structure as the record is handled by both libraries. The class and the record should be the same, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The Delphi output is legal JSON.  Internally, `REST.TJson` is hard-coded to marshal a record as a JSON array.  That is simply how it is implemented, it is by design, not a bug.  It is just another way to represent data.  SuperObject chooses to be more explicit.  That is also OK.  Two different implementations, two different representations.  The JSON spec allows for both.

Comment: Someday someone can invite his implementation in which an integer field is represented like an JSON array with 5 elements and the actual number will be stored in 3rd position. JSON spec also allows this, but it's not portable and is strange. Representing a key/value pairs as an array of ordered values is a "protocol" invented by the Vendor and is also not portable and also strange. That is. I prefer to post a QC for enhancement :)